# What is the difference between 네 and 네요 to express admiration?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, conjugation

I'm learning about [the usage of 네 to the stem of the verb to express admiration](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/upper-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-4-lessons-76-83/lesson-83/), but I don't understand the difference between 네 and 네요.

What is the difference between them? Is 네요 more formal much like 없어요 and 없어, or something others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really just a difference in politeness levels. -네 is used in talking with very close friends or younger people, or in making a comment to yourself. -네요 is used when making a comment to someone older or superior to you.